# Applying bootstrap popover only on regex match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to apply this popover

```
$('.body').popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: 'top',
  container: 'body',
  content: function () {
    return '<img src="'+$(this).attr('href') + '" />';
  }
});
```

only if `/(jpg|gif|png)$/.test($(this).attr('href'))`

I am not sure how to do this.. since I can't do the condition before, and if I am already inside the popover it is too late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using filter to filter it like so

```
$('.body').filter(function() {
  return /(jpg|gif|png)$/.test($(this).attr('href'))
}).popover({ html: true,
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'top',
            container: 'body',
            content: function () {
                return '<img src="'+$(this).attr('href') + '" />';
             }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this in the popover, you could iterate through all the items with class `body` and add a new class (e.g. `imgbody`) in the event that it matches certain conditions. You then create the popovers for that class only.

So:

```
$('.body').each(function(index, elem) {
  if (/(jpg|gif|png)$/.test($(elem).attr('href')))
     $(elem).addClass("imgbody");
});
$(".imgbody").popover({ ...
```

Comment: thats possible, I ended up using filter()

Comment: your solution is, however, more flexible in the long run